# Blank page at start of pdf created via pandoc

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc

When I export a Markdown file (created using Sublime Text 2) via pandoc I am getting a blank page at the start of my document and another blank page after my table of contents.

This is the pandoc export command I am currently using:

`pandoc markdownfile.md -o test.pdf --toc -V geometry:margin=0.5in -- variable fontsize=10pt --variable fontfamily=utopia --variable linkcolor=blue --latex-engine=xelatex`

How do I remove these blank pages?

Using OS X Yosemite v10.10.

**Edit: sample markdown file**

```
% **Manual**
% version 0
% ![](/users/jpmccarthy/desktop/docs/pdf/images/1-manual-cover.png)\

\pagebreak

![](/users/jpmccarthy/desktop/docs/pdf/images/2-manual-intro.png)\

\pagebreak

## 1.  Introduction

### 1.1 Audience 

Section describing intended audience . . .
```

Comment: did you change anything to your pandoc latex template? like the `documentclass`? Do you have any variable set up in the yaml front matter of your markdown? You should also post a minimal markdown file that reproduces the problem.

Comment: also, you have an extra space between `--` and `variable fontsize`

Comment: @scoa extra space removed, no change - markdown file snippet added to question (issue only exists at start of exported pdf). Thanks for answering.

Comment: the problem might be with your images... Could you post a screenshot of the output, and maybe try with smaller images?

Comment: @scoa The output is: blank page > 1-manual-cover.png > toc > blank page > 2-manual-intro

Comment: I can, of course, rearrange the pdf pages (and delete blank pages), but I then lose the document's search functionality.